# Need to make call with complex JSON to the router

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, jackson

I am coding my first Android application and I just started to work with JSON. I need to transfer username and password using JSON to the router and get response from the router. But, I cannot figure out how to make JSON call to the router. My JSON string is made of a JSON object, an Array and an object again and I don't know how to make a JSON call to the router to transfer this complex JSON. I am using Jackson.2.2.2 library. So, my question is, how to make a JSON call to the router to transfer this complex JSON string.

> Below is my JSON string:

```
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ "00000000000000000000000000000000", "session", "login", { "username": "uname", "password": "upassword"  } ] } http://192.168.1.1/ubus
```

I need to transfer Username and Password.

Adding some of my code below:

> RESTRequest.java

```
public class RESTRequest {

private static final String TAG = JacksonUtil.class.getSimpleName();
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

//Constructor with no parameter
public RESTRequest(){

}

/**
 * Making web service call
 */
public String makeWebServiceCall(String url, int requestmethod){
    return this.makeWebServiceCall(url, requestmethod, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 */
public String makeWebServiceCall(String urladdress, int requestmethod, HashMap<String, String> params){

    URL url;
    String responce = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urladdress);

        HttpURLConnection urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlconn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        urlconn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlconn.setDoInput(true);
        urlconn.setDoOutput(true);

        if(requestmethod == POST){
            urlconn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        }else if(requestmethod == GET){
            urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }

        if(params != null){
            OutputStream outputstream = urlconn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream, "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");

                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            bufferedWriter.write(result.toString());

            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputstream.close();
        }

        int responceCode = urlconn.getResponseCode();

        if(responceCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlconn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                responce += line;
            }
        }else {
            responce = "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException parsing to json", e);
    }

    return response;
}
```

> JacksonUtil

```
public class JacksonUtil {

private static final String TAG = JacksonUtil.class.getSimpleName();
private static ObjectMapper mapper;
private static TypeFactory factory;

private JacksonUtil() {
}

private static ObjectMapper getMapper() {
    if (mapper == null) {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        factory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
    }
    return mapper;
}

public static <T> String fromObject(T object) {
    try {
        return getMapper().writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException parsing to json", e);
    } /*catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(App.class.getSimpleName(), "Exception", e);
            Log.e("JacksonUtil", "FromObject");
        }*/
    return null;
}

public static <T> T toObject(InputStream is, Class<T> o) {
    try {
        return getMapper().readValue(is, o);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException parsing from json", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception parsing from json", e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static <T> T toObject(String json, Class<T> o) {
    if (json == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return getMapper().readValue(json, o);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException parsing from json", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception parsing from json", e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static <T> T toObject(String json, TypeReference<T> type) {
    try {
        return getMapper().readValue(json, type);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException parsing from json", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception parsing from json", e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static <T> T toCollection(String json, Class<? extends Collection> list, Class types) {
    try {
        return getMapper().readValue(json, factory.constructCollectionType(list, types));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException parsing from json", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception parsing from json", e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static <T> T toCollection(InputStream is, Class<? extends Collection> list, Class types) throws Exception {
    return getMapper().readValue(is, factory.constructCollectionType(list, types));
}
```

Comment: You have posted quite a bit of code, but to me it is not obvious where exactly your problem lies. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I need to transfer username and password using JSON to the router and get response from the router, but I cannot figure out how to make JSON call to the router. There is missing code with JSON call and I don't know how to write it, because my JSON string is made from JSON object, Array and object again. First time working with JSON and couldn't find any useful examples.

Comment: @Jonas Seputis please edit the question description and add the above details from your comments there.